# Syntax highlighting in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using Gnome Terminal. All my input have the same color.

But today I was using Powershell in Windows and it has different colors for a command, for flags and for options.

How I can do the same in Ubuntu?
I have tried [themes](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/blob/master/content/themes.md), but they only change the background but not my input.

(I took image from internet, so pay attention only to upper selection)
[image]

**UPD.** 
I want to have colors when I write command. For example when I write `git commit -m "Hello"` - `git` should be yellow, `commit` white, `-m` grey and `"Hello"` green.

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do? Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to have colors when I write command. For example when I write `git commit -m "Hello"` - *git* should be yellow, *commit*  white *-m* grey and *"Hello"* green.

Comment: This is called syntax highlighting. Recent versions of IPython support it, but I'm not sure how to get it in Bash.

Comment: I found this: [Is there any way to get bash to have syntax highlighting like fish?](https://superuser.com/q/304211/443564) Looks like it's difficult...

Comment: Not bash, but fish will - https://hackercodex.com/guide/install-fish-shell-mac-ubuntu/ or similar

Comment: Switching shells is the quickest way to get it. Zsh or fish, maybe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash (the default shell of Ubuntu) doesn't have this ability.  It uses GNU readline, and likely would be a [serious effort](https://superuser.com/q/304211/443564) to implement it.

But, there are mechanisms to use different shells.  Two common ones that are talked about a lot are:

- [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) - "Your terminal never felt *this* good before.
- [fish](https://fishshell.com/) - "A command line shell for the 90s"

See the respective sites for up to date setup instructions.  But in general the shells are not that hard to configure.  Fish, for instance is:

```
sudo apt install fish
chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
# logout/login
```

Then, if you want to switch back

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
# logout/login
```

oh-my-zsh isn't *as* easy, but it's the same idea.